# Как узнать номер одного из дочерних элементов Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на один определённый дочерний элемент выводило его порядковый номер относительно родительского элемента. При этом классы добавлять нельзя!

Вот пример HTML кода

```
<ul>

    <li></li>

    <li></li>

    <li></li>

</ul>

<ul>

    <li></li>

    <li></li>

    <li></li>

    <li></li>

</ul>
```

Скрипт JS, jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const node = e.target.parentNode;

  console.log([...node.children].indexOf(e.target));
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```